# How to wait for a function, which contains promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

If we have this function

```
const getData = () => {
  foo()
  .then(result => {
     return result;
   })
  .catch(error => {
     return error;
   });
};
```

Although `getData` is not a promise itself, but it contains a promise, which is asyncrnous.

So what is the best way to wait for `getData` to return something. `Async / Await` doesn't work cause they work with promises.

Thanks.

Comment: Add `return` before `foo`: `return foo().then(...).catch(...)` and call `getData` as `getData().then(...)` or `await getData()`

Comment: To build up on @Yousaf's comment, currently `getData()` doesn't return anything. You need to make it return a Promise, so you can await it or chain `.then()` to it.

Comment: **Note:** Instead of returning `error` from the callback function of `catch`, throw it; returning an error or any value other than a rejected promise will _fulfill_ the promise returned by `getData()` function which may or may not what you want. Alternatively, you could write `getData()` function as one liner: `const getData => foo()` and add the `catch` block in the code that calls the `getData` function.

Comment: As I understand the problem is about getting the `result` returned without wrapping it in a `Promise`.
There are two ways. One is providing a callback that accepts the `result`:
```
  const getData = (cb) => {
    foo()
    .then(result => {
     cb(result);
       return result;
     })
    .catch(error => {
       return error;
     });
  };
```
And also you can use some blocking code that idles while the `result` is waiting for the assignment, but this is very bad practice I suspect.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, `getData()` doesn't return anything. You need to make it return a Promise, so you can `await` it or chain `.then()` to it.

```
const getData = () => {
  return foo() // <-- here
  .then(result => {
     return result;
   })
  .catch(error => {
     throw error;
   });
};

// Now you can do :
getData().then(...)
// or :
const data = await getData();
```

In this case, you can also omit the curly braces and the explicit `return`, and make it implicit :

```
const getData = () => foo()
  .then(result => {
     return result;
   })
  .catch(error => {
     throw error;
   });
```

Hey but what's that :

```
.then(result => {
         return result;
})
```

This does nothing. It takes a value and simply returns it without doing anything. You can remove it.

You can now rewrite getData() this way :

```
const getData = async () => {
    try {
      return await foo()
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
}
```

For that matter, this :

```
.catch(error => { throw error; });
```

or this :

```
catch (error) { throw error; }
```

are also pretty useless, they just "relay" (bubble up) the error that has to be caught in the calling function.

Now it's obvious `getData` does pretty much only one thing, it's returning `foo()`, which is a Promise. It's only a wrapper around a Promise... so it's actually pretty useless.

Bottom line, `detData()` is useless altogether. `foo` is a Promise; writing a function that returns a Promise so you can use it like a Promise is just... a Promise with an extra step. Just use `foo` directly.

```
let result;
try {
  result = await foo();
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: You're correct, I have edited my answer, thanks

Comment: Thanks. It was just to show the structure. Of course there's some operations and process in `getData`. Not simply returning what it gets.

Comment: Ah, nevermind. This might still be useful in one way or another :)

Answer (score 1):

This will not work because getData is not returning a value. You can add a return statement before foo call and wait for the return value.

```
const getData = () => {
  return foo();
};

getData().then(data => {
  console.log(data);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To wait for an operation you must return a Promise or use a callback. The code snippet below runs and should illustrate how this works. I implemented a sample `foo` function that is actually asynchronous (wait for 1 second before returning the data '12345'). I used `async`/`await` to illustrate how that can work, but you can equally return the result of `foo` and use `then` instead.

```js
const foo = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve('12345'), 1000);
  });
}
const getData = async () => {
  const data = await foo();
  console.log(`Data is ${data}`);
  return data;
};

getData()
  .then(() => console.log('complete'))
  .catch(err => console.log(`oops: ${err}`));
  
console.log('this prints first since async operation is still pending');
```